# Display the title of a UWP application containing a NavigationView and an acrylic design extended to the title bar

Tags: uwp, navigationview

My UWP app has a NavigationView and uses Fluent Design with extended acrylic in the title bar.
So you have to draw the application title yourself, which normally appears automatically in the title bar, with a TextBlock control using CaptionTextBlockStyle. I tried to apply the example provided by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar)
But unfortunately this example does not take into account the extended acrylic in the title bar. Below the modified XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="MesProjets.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MesProjets"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<Page.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="imagefond" 
                ImageSource="/Assets/Images/Wallpaper.png"
                Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

    <Style TargetType="NavigationView">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>



<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
              TintColor="DarkOliveGreen"
              TintOpacity="0.6"
              FallbackColor="DarkGray"/>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
              TintColor="DarkOliveGreen"
              TintOpacity="0.6"
              FallbackColor="DarkGray"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForeground" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="GreenYellow"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed" Color="GreenYellow"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <!--<TextBlock Text="Mes Projets"
               Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 

               Margin="0,8,0,0"/>-->

    <!--<Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
         --><!--Width of the padding columns is set in LayoutMetricsChanged handler. 
         Using padding columns instead of Margin ensures that the background
     paints the area under the caption control buttons (for transparent buttons).--><!-- 
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        --><!--<Image Source="Assets/Square44x44Logo.png" 
       Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Width="20" Height="20" Margin="12,0"/>--><!--
        <TextBlock Text="Mes Projets" 
           Grid.Column="1" 
           Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 
           Margin="10,8,0,0"/>
    </Grid>-->



    <NavigationView x:Name="NavViewMain"
                    PaneTitle="  Mes Projets"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Loaded="NavViewMain_Loaded"
                    SelectionChanged="NavViewMain_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemInvoked="NavViewMain_ItemInvoked"
                    CompactModeThresholdWidth="0"
                    ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1000"
                    OpenPaneLength="250"
                    FontSize="24"
                    IsSettingsVisible="{Binding ElementName=settingsCheck,Path=IsChecked}" IsTabStop="False"
                    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                    >

        <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<Grid Margin="100,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        -->
                <!--<ColumnDefinition/>-->
                <!--
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
                <TextBlock  x:Name="appTitle" 
                                Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                FontSize="28"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                x:Uid="MainPageTitre"/>
                <!--</Grid>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Tag="ListeProjets_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_ListeProjets" x:Uid="NVItem1" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Tag="ProjetsPrevus_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_ProjetsPrevus" x:Uid="NVItem2" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Tag="ProjetsEnCours_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_ProjetsEnCours" x:Uid="NVItem3" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Tag="ProjetsRealises_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_ProjetsRealises" x:Uid="NVItem4" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="XboxOneConsole" Tag="ListeMonnaies_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_ListeMonnaies" x:Uid="NVItem5" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Tag="Backup_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Backup" x:Uid="NVItem6" />
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Tag="Aide_Page" >
                <TextBlock Tag="Nav_Aide" x:Uid="NVItem7" />
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame">
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

The result is that the title of the application appears in the upper left, but in a title bar that should not normally exist.
How do I get the same result we have with the Calendar app?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationView` is an integrated combination control, if you want to add a `TextBlock` on the `PaneToggleButton`, you can only modify the template of the `NavigationView`.

This is an example:

**xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="NavigationView">
    <Setter Property="PaneToggleButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="CompactPaneLength" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewCompactPaneLength}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationView">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisplayModeGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AppTitle.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootSplitView.PaneBackground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Minimal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContent.Margin" Value="48,5,0,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopNavigationMinimal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MinimalWithBackButton">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContent.Margin" Value="104,5,0,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TogglePaneGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TogglePaneButtonVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TogglePaneButtonCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneContentGridToggleButtonRow.Height" Value="4" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContent.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SettingsGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="SettingsVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="SettingsCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SettingsNavPaneItem.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="SettingsTopNavPaneItem.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AutoSuggestGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AutoSuggestArea.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="TopPaneAutoSuggestArea.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotClosedCompact" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ClosedCompact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AppTitle.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneToggleButtonGrid.Padding" Value="0,25,0,0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="PaneAutoSuggestButton.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStateListSizeGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ListSizeFull" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ListSizeCompact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MenuItemsHost.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <!-- This is essentially a TemplateBinding: -->
                                    <Setter Target="MenuItemsHost.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SettingsNavPaneItem.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="SettingsNavPaneItem.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                    <Setter Target="PaneTitleTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="PaneHeaderContentBorder.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="PaneCustomContentBorder.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="PaneCustomContentBorder.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                    <Setter Target="FooterContentBorder.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="FooterContentBorder.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TitleBarVisibilityGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TitleBarVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TitleBarCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PaneContentGrid.Margin" Value="0,32,0,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OverflowLabelGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowButtonWithLabel" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowButtonNoLabel">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="TopNavOverflowButton.Style" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewOverflowButtonNoLabelStyleWhenPaneOnTop}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BackButtonGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackButtonVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackButtonCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="BackButtonPlaceholderOnTopNav.Width" Value="0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid
                    x:Name="PaneToggleButtonGrid"
                    Margin="0,0,0,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="100">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock 
                        Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="10,5" x:Name="AppTitle"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="MainPageTitre"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="TogglePaneTopPadding"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                          />

                        <Grid x:Name="ButtonHolderGrid" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Button 
                            x:Name="NavigationViewBackButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.BackButtonVisibility}"
                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsBackEnabled}">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="NavigationViewBackButtonToolTip" />
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                            x:Name="TogglePaneButton"
                            Style="{TemplateBinding PaneToggleButtonStyle}"
                            AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.PaneToggleButtonVisibility}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock
                                x:Name="PaneTitleTextBlock" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding PaneTitle}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Style="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                    <Grid>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="TopNavArea" Background="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTopPaneBackground}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.ZIndex="1" XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">

                                    <Grid x:Name="TopNavTopPadding"
                                      Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.TopPadding}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.TopPaneVisibility}"/>

                                    <Grid x:Name="TopNavGrid" 
                                      Height="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTopPaneHeight}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.TopPaneVisibility}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="BackButtonPlaceholderOnTopNav" Width="{ThemeResource NavigationBackButtonWidth}" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="48" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Grid 
                                        x:Name="TopNavLeftPadding" 
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Width="0"/>

                                        <ContentControl
                                        x:Name="PaneHeaderOnTopPane"
                                        IsTabStop="False"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Grid.Column="2"/>

                                        <!-- Top nav list -->
                                        <NavigationViewList AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation" x:Name="TopNavMenuItemsHost" Grid.Column="3" SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.SingleSelectionFollowsFocus}">
                                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                <TransitionCollection />
                                            </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                        </NavigationViewList>

                                        <Button 
                                        x:Name="TopNavOverflowButton"
                                        Grid.Column="4"

                                        Content="More"
                                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationViewOverflowButtonStyleWhenPaneOnTop}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.OverflowButtonVisibility}">

                                            <Button.Flyout>
                                                <Flyout Placement="Bottom" ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False">
                                                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,8" />
                                                            <!-- Set negative top margin to make the flyout align exactly with the button -->
                                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-4,0,0" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                                    <NavigationViewList x:Name="TopNavMenuItemsOverflowHost" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="False" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                                                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                            <TransitionCollection />
                                                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                    </NavigationViewList>
                                                </Flyout>
                                            </Button.Flyout>
                                        </Button>

                                        <ContentControl
                                        x:Name="PaneCustomContentOnTopPane"
                                        IsTabStop="False"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Grid.Column="5"/>

                                        <Grid
                                        x:Name="TopPaneAutoSuggestArea"
                                        Height="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTopPaneHeight}"
                                        Grid.Column="6">

                                            <ContentControl
                                            x:Name="TopPaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter"
                                            Margin="12,0,12,0"
                                            MinWidth="48"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <ContentControl
                                        x:Name="PaneFooterOnTopPane"
                                        IsTabStop="False"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Grid.Column="7" />
                                        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SettingsTopNavPaneItem" Style="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSettingsItemStyleWhenOnTopPane}" Grid.Column="8" Icon="Setting" />

                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border
                                    x:Name="TopNavContentOverlayAreaGrid"
                                    Child="{TemplateBinding ContentOverlay}" />
                                </StackPanel>

                                <SplitView
                                x:Name="RootSplitView"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                CompactPaneLength="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"
                                DisplayMode="Inline"
                                IsPaneOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                OpenPaneLength="{TemplateBinding OpenPaneLength}"
                                PaneBackground="{ThemeResource NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground}"

                                Grid.Row="1">

                                    <SplitView.Pane>
                                        <Grid 
                                        x:Name="PaneContentGrid"
                                        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.LeftPaneVisibility}">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                                <!-- above button margin + back button space -->
                                                <RowDefinition x:Name="PaneContentGridToggleButtonRow" Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                                                <!-- above list margin -->
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Grid x:Name="ContentPaneTopPadding"
                                              Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.TopPadding}"/>

                                            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Height="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonHeight}">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource PaneToggleButtonWidth}" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <ContentControl
                                                x:Name="PaneHeaderContentBorder"
                                                IsTabStop="False"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Grid.Column="1" />
                                            </Grid>

                                            <Grid
                                            x:Name="AutoSuggestArea"
                                            Grid.Row="3"
                                            Height="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTopPaneHeight}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                                <ContentControl
                                                x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestBoxPresenter"
                                                Margin="{ThemeResource NavigationViewAutoSuggestBoxMargin}"
                                                IsTabStop="False"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

                                                <Button
                                                x:Name="PaneAutoSuggestButton"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                Style="{ThemeResource NavigationViewPaneSearchButtonStyle}"
                                                Width="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"/>
                                            </Grid>

                                            <ContentControl
                                            x:Name="PaneCustomContentBorder"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Grid.Row="4" />

                                            <!-- Left nav list -->
                                            <NavigationViewList x:Name="MenuItemsHost" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,0,0,20" SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.SingleSelectionFollowsFocus}" />

                                            <ContentControl
                                            x:Name="FooterContentBorder"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Grid.Row="7" />
                                            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SettingsNavPaneItem" Grid.Row="8" Icon="Setting" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </SplitView.Pane>

                                    <SplitView.Content>
                                        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Grid x:Name="ContentTopPadding"
                                              Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.TopPadding}"
                                              Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.LeftPaneVisibility}"/>

                                            <ContentControl
                                            x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            MinHeight="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonHeight}"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Style="{StaticResource NavigationViewTitleHeaderContentControlTextStyle}"/>

                                            <ContentPresenter
                                            AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Main"
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </SplitView.Content>
                                </SplitView>

                            </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
}
```

---

In a grid called `PaneToggleButtonGrid`, we added a `TextBlock` to display the app title. In addition, we need to add some status effects. In `<VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStateGroup">`, we added code that controls `AppTitle` visibility and some UI handling.

---

BTW, if you need some more complicated effects, such as dynamically changing the value of `AppTitle`, then you can try to use `SplitView` and `Frame` to build a 
custom `NavigationView` to meet your needs.

Best regards.

Comment: Hello Richard, I applied the modifications you proposed to the XAML code of MainPage.xaml and I have several problems: In the <Button> section, the ShouldConstrainToRootBounds property is not recognized. So I deleted this section because I don't use this button. That being done, I have another error that appears: just after </Page.Resources> the <Grid> section is in error (the resource "Unknown" has an incompatible type). And the program crash: The program '[13160] MesProjets.exe' stopped with the code -1 (0xffffffff). Thank you for helping me, I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hi, you can choose not to use this Button, but you can't delete it. Because `NavigationView` has functions that depend on this Button. If you delete this Button, a resource named `TopNavOverflowButton` cannot be found inside the control and an error will be reported.

Comment: Hello Richard, I understand that I cannot delete the code of this <Button>, but if I use your example without modifying it, the line <Flyout Placement = "Bottom" ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = "False"> is in error (the ShouldConstrainToRootBounds member is not recognized or is not accessible).This is why I commented on the <Button.Flyout> part. And it is after this action that I got the error The resource "Unknown" has an incompatible type on the first declaration <Grid>. It’s as if </Page.Resources> is not recognized. Thank you for you help.

Comment: I forgot to say that the target version and the minimum version are Windows 10 version 1809 (10.0; build 17763). The problem may have come from there?

Comment: Hi. The control default template is generated based on the current system version and is located in the `generic.xaml` file. The system version I used to generate this template is `1909`. If your system is `1809`, you may need to find the `generic.xaml` file of your current system, copy the `NavigationView` template code, and modify it accordingly. The `generic.xaml` file is usually located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\your_system_version\Generic`

Comment: Hello Richard, What do you mean exactly by modify it accordingly? I modified the generic.xaml file in the 10.0.17763.0 folder by adding the lines of your code that I did not find in the original file. But nothing works in VS anymore (many errors in other pages: The name 'mottoPSProj' does not exist in the current context). And the initial error regarding ShouldConstrainToRootBounds still exists. What to do ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, What I mean is to find the style of `TargetType ="NavigationView"`, copy it to your project and modify it. `generic.xaml` stores all the resources shared by UWP and the system and cannot be modified directly. With the system upgrade, the content in `generic.xaml` will also change. If the style I provided is not applicable to 1809, you need to copy from the current system's `generic.xaml` Corresponding `Style`. `Popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` is an attribute added only in 1903. In 1809, please delete this attribute instead of deleting `Button.Flyout`

Comment: Thank you Richard. Now I understand better, I'll make the changes this afternoon and tell you if it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: If there is new progress, please let me know and I will keep focus on this case

Comment: Hello Richard, I copied the <Style TargetType = "NavigationView"> code part of the generic.xaml file into the MainPage.xaml code, making the modifications you indicated so that the title is visible. Unfortunately, the <Grid> section is always in error (the resource "Unknown" has an incompatible type). You can find the complete MainPage.xaml code here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am0yZGVkguZvjc1N2ahFnDKdKyaOpg?e=bx977g.  If you have time to look at it it would be very nice because I can't find the error. I hope I can finally display the title of my application. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, you can try to clean the project and rebuild it. I copied your code and it runs successfully without modification, although the style is slightly different.

Comment: Hello Richard, I don't understand: I cleaned the project, then did a rebuild, and still the same problem: the <Grid> section is always in error (the resource "Unknown" has an incompatible type). Did you take the test with VS 2017 or VS 2019?

Comment: Hi, I use the Visual Studio 2019 to test it. You can try to create a new blank project, then copy the xaml code over and delete the events in it to see if there is the same problem. If the new project is normal, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders of the source project and rebuild the project

Comment: I already did this test yesterday, and I have the same problem in the same place (the first <Grid>). I have to keep VS 2017 because I have an app on the store made with this version. I'll try to install VS 2019, but I don't have much space on my system partition anymore. I inform you as soon as I have been able to test with VS 2019. Thank you and see you soon.

Comment: Hi, I tested with Visual Studio 2017 and the XAML editor did prompt this issue, I created a new Grid and copied the contents of the grid in question to the new Grid, after I rebuilt the project once, the warning disappeared. It does not affect normal debugging. If your problem persists, you can try to update the system or the Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, thank you Richard. I'm testing this solution this afternoon and giving you the result.

Comment: Hi Richard. I did the same thing, and everything is fine until build. After the build, the same error reappears. I deleted the Bin and Obj folders before doing a rebuild and I have the same error. Maybe the problem comes from VS. I will install VS 2019 and tell you if that solves the problem. Thank you again for all.

Comment: Hi, this is indeed a very confusing question, looking forward to your test results

Comment: Hi Richard, I just tested the solution with VS 2019. Unfortunately, it's even worse than with VS 2017: I still have the same error on the <Grid> element, but in addition, there are lots of errors like this: "failure to locate the element named HeaderContent on the line <Setter Target =" HeaderContent.Margin "Value =" 48,5,0,0 "/>. I have not changed anything in the project: target version Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; Build 17763) and same for the minimum version. What else can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just changed the minimum and target version for Build 18362, I copy the <Style TargetType="NavigationView"> without any modification compared to the generic.xaml file, but that doesn't change anything: the errors are still there.

Comment: Hi, although I encountered the same error as you the first time I copied the code, it was temporary for me (the error disappeared after rebuilt). You can try to create the `NavigationView` style code in `App.Resources` in **App.xaml**, this separation way may work

Comment: Hello Richard, I was finally able to modify my program to make it work properly. I failed to embed the code <Style ..."> in the App.xaml file. I then created a resource file that I called Dictonary1.xaml, in which I copied the code <Style ...">. Then I modified the MainPage.xaml file so that it takes this resource file into account. There is still a small problem: when the NavigationView is in reduced mode, the text does not disappear. I will ask a new question about this. Thank you very much for your help, without you I would never have found the solution.

Comment: Hi, Glad to see you found a solution. Regarding the `AppTitle` not disappearing in the `Compact` state. Please see the instructions I made in the answer, you need to add the code to set `AppTitle.Visibility` to Collapsed under `Style / VisualStateGroups / PaneStateGroup / ClosedCompact`

Comment: Hello Richard, you really are a great developer. I had not seen these changes. I corrected them, and everything works perfectly. Bravo and thank you again.